# Entity Framework 6 System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-6

In a unit test method, I'm systematically getting a `ThreadAbortException` whenever I call `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync` (on an Entity Framework 6 `DbContext` instance) after another async method call like `SingleOrDefaultAsync` or `ToListAsync`.

It looks like calling `SaveChanges/SaveChangesAsync` on a different thread than the one which created the `DbContext` instance is the cause of the problem, which is strange. In my knowledge it is nothing uncommon in the fact that the execution of the code after the await keyword is continued by a different worker thread.

What's wrong in my code? Thank you in advance for your answers!

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    // worker thread id =  n
    SomeDto dto= await ctx.SomeDtoSet.Where(x => x.SomeDto Id == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    // worker thread id =  n + 1
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    // ctx.SaveChangesAsync(); behaves similarly
}
```

Comment: Are multiple threads using the same db context instance at the same time? There is no showing of how you are using threading in your example code. Please include a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably multiple Thread using MyContext.You might create new instance and try on it. Can u check it with try-catch

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext()){
try{
// worker thread id =  n
SomeDto dto= await ctx.SomeDtoSet.Where(x => x.SomeDto Id == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
// worker thread id =  n + 1
ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
{
Thread.ResetAbort();
}}
```